# Insert into table but unsure of foreign key

Tags: mysql

Table `Order`

```
oid  payerName address
1       james    1 brown
2       smith     2  smith
```

Table  `order_item`

```
oid  type  price
1    AN94  3000
2    AK47  1000
```

order_item as a foreign from Order.

oid is an auto increment in `Order` Table
but in `order_item` table it is not(dont know if thats is the  right way to do it)

I have an insert statement which inserts into both tables at the same  time. I was wonder if it the right to make order_item oid an auto  increment as well? because the is not other way I can make it copy the oid from order table.

What is the  best approach to this small issue.

Comment: if `oid` in `order_item` table is referring to `oid` field in order table then it shouldn't be auto increment. I assume that an order can have many items in it. a better approach is adding `oiid` to `order_item` table and make it auto increment. (I dont know if you even need that.)

Comment: @nyzm yes an order can have more than  1 item. The reason why i need to link both item is that one of them as info about the items being ordered and another as info about the items themselves, e.g. totalprice, type, amount, itemgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You shouldn't make order id field in `order_items` table to be `auto_increment`**. To obtain a value of auto generated id when you insert a row in `orders` table use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

It's OK to have it's own `auto_increment` id column in `order_items`.  Sometimes it comes very handy *(e.g. when you want to update an individual `order_item` row you can reference it by its own id rather than by a combination of columns)*.

That being said proposed schema might look like

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(`order_id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
 `payerName` varchar(5), 
 `address` varchar(8)
);
CREATE TABLE order_items
(`order_item_id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
 `order_id` int, 
 `type` varchar(4), 
 `price` decimal(19,2),
 foreign key (order_id) references orders (order_id)
);
```

*Names of id columns has been intentionally renamed in my example for clarity. You don't have to change yours obviously.*

Now to insert an order and an order item you do

```
INSERT INTO orders (`payerName`, `address`)
VALUES ('james', '1 brown');

INSERT INTO order_items (`order_id`, `type`, `price`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'AN94', 3000);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8c6bf/1)** demo

---

You didn't mention PDO in your question but your code using it might look something like this

```php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'userpwd');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //$db->beginTransaction();

    $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (`payerName`, `address`) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $query->execute(array('james', '1 brown'));

    $order_id = $db->lastInsertId();

    $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO order_items (`order_id`, `type`, `price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $query->execute(array($order_id, 'AN94', 3000));

    //$db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage();
}
$query = null;
$db = null;
```

Comment: correct me if am wrong. But you  are saying if i use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` it will automatically insert the id from `order table` into the foreign key in `order_item table`?

Comment: It will return an auto generated value for the most recent INSERT statement in your session. Therefore if you first insert into orders and then subsequently use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` it will return an id for the order that you just inserted. Then you use it when you insert rows into `order_items` table.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesnt seem to work in PDO `:LAST_INSERT_ID()` or just `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: In PDO you should use **[`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)**

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi See updated answer for an example of doing it with PDO

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi You're very welcome. I'm glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since order_item->oid depends on order->oid, Order should exist first before the order_item

This one is right because the oid(1) exist in the order table

> `insert into order_item (oid,type,price) values('1','AN94','3000')`

This one is wrong because the oid(3) doesn't exist in the order table

> `insert into order_item (oid,type,price)values('3','sample','3333')`

BTW the table order-oid should be a primary key

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi the answer is base from what i understood

Answer (score 0):

## Orders

**order_id**(*auto inc*), payer_name, address

## Order Items

order_item_id(*auto inc*), **order_id**, **item_id**, type, quantity, unit_price

## Product

**item_id**(*auto inc*), item_name, item_unit_price, item_group

Comment: Nice layout @nyzm  but my question is to do with inserting while the `order_id` is passed to `Order Items`  while it getting insert to `Orders`

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood your question. I think peter's answer is pointing to the right direction.